# MS dynamics AX 2009 time zone problem

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

My question is related to population of modified date time field in AX during any posting.

Suppose  I have a server  at singapore and i am working through a client India,and the current time in singapore is 12 p.m and that in India is 9 a.m. Then while I am posting  any purchase order packing slip, it is populating the modified date time  field with the time of singapore i.e 12 p.m. But I require  the Indian time i.e 9 a.m. to be populated there. How is it possible?

Regards
SSM

Answer (score 3):

The "ModifiedDateTime" field is of the type utcDateTime. In the database the field value stored will be the date/time in UTC/GMT. In the UI the field is then converted and displayed using your own time-zone.

The location of your server in Singapore is as such not relevant.

If your users in India gets a wrong date/time displayed, you should set the time-zone for the individual users in the user options form "Tools/Options".